# Virtual screen larger than 4096x4096 using xrandr

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, multiple-monitors, resolution, xrandr

I have a triple monitor setup with a 1920x1200 monitor in the middle and two rotated 1600x1200s on the sides, for a total requirement of 4320x1600. I recently installed xubuntu and I'm trying to use xrandr to set this up, and can't figure out how to do it. I always get an error as follows, whatever I try (root, using 1:1 resolutions and creating an xorg.conf file and putting a Virtual line in it all don't work).

```
X@X:~$ xrandr --fb 4320x1600
xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 4096x4096 (desired size 4320x1600)
```

If it matters I'm using two GeForce 7300 GS with two monitors on DVI and one on VGA. All three monitors show up and I can enable any combination of two at once just fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you use the proprietay NVidia drivers? If yes, you could use the NVidia settings tool...

Comment: See my answer at http://askubuntu.com/questions/536175/increase-virtual-screen-size-past-4096-x-4096-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to find the correct Screen-Display SubSection in your existing `xorg.conf` and add the `Virtual` entry. If the entry does not exist, you'll need to create the rest of your configuration as well.

```
Section "Screen"
  …
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth 32
    Virtual 8192 8192
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

See http://x.debian.net/howto/use-xrandr.html for more details. Beware that some graphics drivers may have hardcoded virtual size limits.

(Added by myself, authentication didn't pick up, so shown as anonymous modification)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.