# Increase virtual screen size past 4096 x 4096 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display, resolution

I have two 27" monitors with a 2560 x 1920 resolution each. When I try to extend my desktop across them both I get the below error:

[image]

So, if I need to increase the maximum virtual screen size? To include a resolution of 5120 x 1920.

I've been trying to do this for about 12 hours now....

I have tried using xrandr arandr and a bunch of other tools recommend on this site and other forums.

I have added a xorg.conf file to /etc/X11 (which didn't exist already, and I generated) which now looks like this:

Note: This is just a snippet from the file (I can post it if needed).

```
Section "Screen"
    SubSection "Display"
                Virtual 5120 4096
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I also tried a bunch of other similar answers, and in the process messed up the xorg server and wasn't able to boot at all until re installing it.

I know xserver changed a bit from 12 to 14, and now uses a bunch of files in /usr/share/xorg.conf.d, which I have also played around with. My understanding is putting a xorg.conf file in the /etc/X11 folder would overrule that anyway (but really, I've been trying anything).

So far nothing has worked.

Some things have had an effect, like me not being able to boot up at all, or get past the logo, which have been solved by root terminalling in safe mode to undo changes or reinstall xserver.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2#the_Virtual_screen for an explanation of why 4096x4096 is the limit.

Comment: Thanks @James I hadn't seen that. It doesn't really explain why 4096 4096 is the limit, just that it is, and the higher the number the more resources are consumed.
tl;dr: Is there any way I can increase to 5120 1920? I really don't want to go back to windows..

Comment: Also take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/347292/virtual-screen-larger-than-4096x4096-using-xrandr for a possible workaround.

Comment: 'Sadly'I went back to windows for this machine.. It simply works.

Answer (score 0):

`xrandr --output VGA1 --rate 60 --mode 1440x900 --fb 5120x1920 --panning 5120x1920`

where --rate xx and mode yyyyXyyy equal a valid mode for your monitor and  the -fb and panning switches specify the desktop size. You'll have to adjust these values to your hardware. I don't have 2 monitors to test this so in your case I think you'd leave off the --panning switch and adjust your situation according to information [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596407/ubuntu-14-04-2-monitors-only-acting-as-1-monitor?rq=1). This does result in a desktop of the desired size however and I can pan around it.

I returned my desktop to normal (for me) with `xrandr --output VGA1 --rate 60 --mode 1440x900 --fb 1440x900`

Tested under Lubuntu 14.04.4 64-bit