# Ubuntu 14.04 -- 2 Monitors only acting as 1 monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, resolution, monitor

So this is an issue of both my monitors ARE working, but they're being treated as if they're one monitor with a resolution of 3840x1200 * 1 instead of 1920x1200 * 2. I'm looking for the standard setup of each monitor acting independently.

When I open `System Settings > Displays` it only shows 1 * Dell 24". I'm running an HP EliteBook 1040 plugged into a dock with 2 display ports. I'm converting both display ports to DVI into the 2 monitors. I'm also not using my laptop screen. The laptop is closed. If I select a resolution of 1920x1200 it mirrors the display on both but the Display window isn't reporting 2 monitors exist, even if I click `Detect Displays`.

```
laptop:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080      60.0 +   59.9     40.0  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 connected primary 3840x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 519mm x 324mm
   1920x1200      60.0 +
   3840x1200      60.0* 
   2560x1024      60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
```

I know just enough to look at all this, but not enough to change any settings to fix this.

Comment: Are you looking to mirror your desktop, or extended desktop?

Comment: I'm wanting to extend them.

Comment: Try this command `xrandr --output eDP1 --left-of LVDS1`

Comment: what happens if the laptop were open?

Comment: I ran `xrandr --output eDP1 --left-of LVDS1` and it didn't do anything. I realized that for some reason ubuntu is thinking that all 3 monitors (includes the built in laptop display I'm not using) are the same display. The little tags that identify the moniters in the top left corner of the displays are all stacked on the far left display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the dual display ports. Ubuntu saw those as a single output. Switching to a DP & VGA resolved the issue.